# Pygame not letting me change color of image

Tags: python, pygame

Ok so im trying to make a simple program thats like the dvd logo bouncing and it works fine until i try to change the color it doesnt work. i might be useing the wrong syntax but heres my coe:

````
pygame.init()
width, height = 400,  400
dvdLogoSpeed = [2, 1]
backgroundColor = 255,  0,  0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

dvdLogo = pygame.image.load("dvdimage.png")
var = pygame.PixelArray(dvdLogo)
dvdLogo = pygame.transform.scale(dvdLogo,(50,50))
dvdLogoRect = dvdLogo.get_rect()
thi=dvdLogo,dvdLogoRect
dvdlogoRect = dvdLogoRect.move_ip(200,6)

while True:
  screen.fill((backgroundColor))
  
  
  screen.blit(dvdLogo,dvdLogoRect)
  dvdLogoRect = dvdLogoRect.move(dvdLogoSpeed)

  if dvdLogoRect.left < 0  or dvdLogoRect.right > width:dvdLogoSpeed[0]+=1;dvdLogoSpeed[0] = -dvdLogoSpeed[0];print("left or right");var.replace((0,0,0),(0,0,255));

  if dvdLogoRect.top < 0  or dvdLogoRect.bottom > height:dvdLogoSpeed[1]+=1;dvdLogoSpeed[1] = -dvdLogoSpeed[1];print("top or bottom");
  
  
  pygame.display.flip()
  time.sleep(10 / 1000)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You made your PixelArray before scaling the surface and reassigning it back into the same variable, so the PixelArray isn't connected to the new surface.

Also, you can use a `pygame.time.Clock` object to regulate your framerate, rather than `time.sleep()`. It's better because you pass in a target framerate, and it tries to match that, adjusting the sleep time depending on how much time the rest of your program takes to execute.

Comment: I moved it but it says File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    screen.blit(dvdLogo,dvdLogoRect)
pygame.error: pygame_Blit: Surfaces must not be locked during blit

Comment: When I use PixelArrays, I create them, change the color, then make them back into the surface. Surfaces need to be locked for direct pixel access, so you can’t blit one that has a pixelarray open. You can use PixelArray.make_surface() to convert it to a new surface or PixelArray.close() to release the lock.